# Type profiles for ML function definitions

Tags: functional-programming, ml

I've searched on Google but I didn't find anything about type profiles for ML.

For example for: `fun bar(a, b, c) = [a, b + hd(c)];`

the type profile is: **int * int * int list -> int list** and for

`fun weird x z = [x, tl(z)]` the type profile is **'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list list**

but I don't understand the logic behind it.

Comment: You probably didn't find anything because nothing is called a "type profile" in ML. Those are the functions' *types*. Search for "type inference" to find the logic behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Type profile" isn't a thing. You probably mean type inference. It is easy in this case. First, note that a curried function definition like yours is equivalent to writing

```
val weird = fn x => fn z => [x, tl z]
```

Now:

1. From the structure of the function it follows that `weird : A -> B -> C` for some types A, B, C.
2. The result is a list, so `C` must be `D list` for some type D.
3. You are invoking `tl` on `z`, so `B` must be `E list` for some type E.
4. The result of that call is the same `E list`, so `D` must be the same as `E list`.
5. `x` is used as an element of the same list, so `A` must be `E list` as well.
6. There is no further constraint, so we can pick an arbitrary `'a` for `E`.

Putting all this together, you get

```
weird : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list list
```